# URL relativity and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I set the url:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('destination', $this->input->server('REQUEST_URI'));
```

Then redirect (doesn't work because it prepends site address):

```
redirect($this->session->userdata('destination'));
```

Is it possible to redirect to an absolute address and would this be a better option considering REQUEST_URI will always be correct on different domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an absolute address for the redirect, like:

`/account/user/1/jason`

or

`http://domain.com/accounts`

A relative link makes no sense here:

`somewhere/link` as it does not specify where this 'location' is to the browser.

Keep in mind the `redirect()` is a HEADER REDIRECT (by default)
Read about it here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: redirect() does get an absolute address for it's argument but it it redirects with the site url prepended.

Comment: @amiawizard, you may want to look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html `referrer()`, if you simply want to do a redirect back?  Easy shortcut using CI available functionality.

Comment: Need to take user to requested page after login occurs, eg. user tries to access edit page, directed to login page, logs in then edit page is opened.

Comment: @amiawizard, yeah I would try the `referrer()` fn, as you would do a redirect from that one page to the login page, simply store the referrer value, and just send them back after successful login. I've done that before with success, otherwise log the URI you are grabbing to see what you actually try to redirect to.